# Correct way to call function from imported python package?

Tags: python, import, youtube-dl

Trying to import the Youtube signature decryption function from `youtube-dl` package but cannot use it, as shown in the code below:

```
import youtube_dl.extractor.youtube

video_id = 'HRfNqYoO9EU'
player_url="https://www.youtube.com/yts/jsbin/player_ias-vfl49f_g4/en_US/base.js" 
unsig= 'ALgxI2wwRgIhAN3cG9UXPZSyZcwx2fTOFvbKT_5CAb475HUHuTjSjOw-AiEAjaY1JtcKuHMQkHyCt5cKGBqazj7mpR4EQ1nwGYvhkEc=' 

signature = youtube_dl.extractor.youtube._decrypt_signature(unsig, video_id, player_url)
print signature
```

Tried multiple ways on importing and referring the module but none worked :(

Here is the relevant file - https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/695720ebe81166b3ee249eb3916e3c7819ef57a8/youtube_dl/extractor/youtube.py#L2005-L2006

The above code errors : `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_decrypt_signature'`

Comment: `_decrypt_signature` is not a method exposed by the `youtube` module, It's a (internal) method of a class inside the `youtube` module. You should instantiate an object of the class and then try to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you refer to is a method of class YoutubeIE

You would have to import it, create an instance and then call it, but as @rdas statet, methods that begin with _ are usually internal methods which may change in later versions of the package and might also not be safe to call.
But if there is no other way, you can start with this code:

```
from youtube_dl.extractor.youtube import YoutubeIE

import youtube_dl.extractor.youtube as yt
help(yt)

yt=YoutubeIE()

video_id = 'HRfNqYoO9EU'
player_url="https://www.youtube.com/yts/jsbin/player_ias-vfl49f_g4/en_US/base.js" 
unsig= 'ALgxI2wwRgIhAN3cG9UXPZSyZcwx2fTOFvbKT_5CAb475HUHuTjSjOw-AiEAjaY1JtcKuHMQkHyCt5cKGBqazj7mpR4EQ1nwGYvhkEc=' 

signature = yt._decrypt_signature(unsig, video_id, player_url)
print(signature)
```

You can call the method this way, but the code fails, because the "_downloader" instance variable is not set correctly. So generally it calls the method, but you'd have to figure out, how to initialize the object properly. The comment of the **init**() method suggests, that you can pass a downloader object directly in the line yt=YoutubeIE().

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I meant by "but you'd have to figure out, how to initialize the object properly". I'd suggest you to have a look at a python tutorial that covers object oriented programming. It won't help you with youtube decryption, but it will help you to understand a few things better. For example this one: https://realpython.com/python3-object-oriented-programming/